# C Language Standard Collections Where Are They?

Tags: c, collections

I have committed to learning C now, I'm good with Python/PHP/Bash but I've decided I'm limited by not being fluent in C.  However I cannot imagine working in a language without lists and hashes, maybe I'm just jumping a gun, but surely there are 'standard' collection libraries.  I do not see any in the GNU standard lib though, any suggestions?

Comment: If you have no other reason than "being limited", I suggest you start learning C++ instead. C++ has vectors, lists, pretty much anything you'd want except hashtables, which will be added in C++0x and are already available in modern compilers.

Comment: I really feel the need to get more acquainted with C as much of the infrastructure that I consume as a VHL Language user is made there and not in C++, bash/PHP/Python being the main ones.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no "standard" set of collection classes for C. Many people simply roll their own as needed.

But of course, there are some libraries filling this gap. For example, [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) offers linked lists, hashtables and various kinds of trees.

Comment: yes this is really what I was asking.  I saw that there was no 'standard'  but I know there's a toolkit that people out there primarily use.  This is probably it. :)  Thanks

Answer (score 12):

C is lower level than you're used to.  There are no standard collections in C outside of the array.

Comment: Ya, OP will be surprised there isn't even function overloading and you can't declare variables in the middle of a function

Comment: @Pyrolistical C99 allows for variable declarations in the middle of a function

Comment: I wasn't clear and I feel bad about that, I thought putting the quotes around 'standard' made it clear that I was asking for a community standard.

Answer (score 8):

There is no standard, but there is a superb alternative that is **far simpler than glib**: Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/).  It includes several efficient collection abstractions and a number of other useful modules.  The software is free, and the book is worth buying.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should try looking into glib. While it's not a standard in the same sense as STL for C++ it's a proven library and is used in a lot of applications.

http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.22/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system, you may find what you're looking for in [sys/queue.h](https://man.openbsd.org/man3/queue.3), which includes "implementations of singly-linked lists, doubly-linked lists, simple queues, and tail queues".

Answer (score 1):

The cdcontainers interface is similar to C ++ STL
https://github.com/maksimandrianov/cdcontainers

```
#define CDC_USE_SHORT_NAMES  // for short names (functions and structs without prefix cdc_*)
#include <cdcontainers/vector.h>
#include <cdcontainers/casts.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector_t *v;
    size_t i;

    if (vector_ctor(&v, NULL) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    if (vector_push_back(v, CDC_INT_TO_PTR(7)) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    if (vector_push_back(v, CDC_INT_TO_PTR(8)) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    for (i = 0; i < vector_size(v); ++i)
        printf("%i ", CDC_PTR_TO_INT(vector_get(v, i)));

    printf("\n");

    vector_dtor(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really standard collections in C.  Being a very low-level language (compared to C++ and more "modern" languages)

C++ adds these via the [Standard Template Library](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/).  Most of the "collections" such as hashing and lists are based on object oriented or generic programming techniques unavailable (other than via convention) in C.

Answer (score 0):

There are no "standard" (as in part of the ISO C standard) container libraries, at least not as of C99.  I've seen several third-party attempts; all had some degree of lossage or another.

C has a very primitive and meager toolkit; I've compared programming in C to building a house with nothing but a handsaw and a claw hammer.