# Finding the common characters present in all strings

Tags: c, string

Compare each string and find the number of common lowercase  letter in all the strings.
Each string is represented by a lowercase  letter from 'a' to 'z'.

#### Example Input:

```
4
abcf
aghb
acbl
bamn
```

#### Example Output:

```
2   // a and b
```

#### Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d\n",&n);

    char str[n][100];         
    char var[0][100];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) { // strings 
        scanf("%99s/n",str[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) { // comparison of first 2 strings
        for(int k=0;k<100;k++)
            if(str[0][i]==str[1][k])
                for(int j=0;j<strlen(str[0]);j++) {
                    var[0][j]=str[0][j];          // storing the common letters in a var array
                }
    }

    for(int l=0; l<strlen(str[1]); l++) { // comparing letters in var array with the letters of all other strings                 
        int x;
        if(var[0][l]==str[l+2][l]);
        x=strlen(var[0]);               // counting the common letters
        printf("%d\n",x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please think of a more descriptive title. This title could apply to thousands of questions.

Comment: `char var[0][100];` is probably not what you want.

Comment: Looks like a school project. If you want to succeed at programming then struggle through the thought process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    char str[n][100];        
    char var[n][26];
    memset(&var[0][0], 0, sizeof(var));

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%99s", str[i]);
        char ch;
        for(int j=0; ch=str[i][j]; ++j){
            if(islower(ch)){
                var[i][ch-'a']=1;//depend on the sequence of character codes
            }
        }
    }

    int x = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<26; ++i){
        int num = 0;
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
            if(var[j][i])
                ++num;
        if(num==n)//all string has character of ('a'+i)
            ++x;
    }
    printf("%d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clean and to the point.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you explain var[i][ch-'a']

Comment: @user3315556 `ch-'a'` : `abcdefghij...` -> `0123456789...`, [0..25] record the presence of the corresponding character replaced by the index of 0-25 from characters a-z.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  if ch='b' so var[0]['b'-'a']=1 ( 'b'-'a' from b to a) ?

Comment: @user3315556 `'b'-'a'` is `1`. `'b'` has `1` larger than code of `'a'` in ASCII character code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to special-case the first two strings here? How about an approach like this (in pseudocode):

```
- create a set of characters, name it letters_in_all_strings
- add every lowercase letter to letters_in_all_strings
- for each input string
  - create a set of characters, name it letters_in_this_string
  - add every character in the input string to letters_in_this_string
  - remove all letters from letters_in_all_strings that are not present in letters_in_this_string
- print out the size of letters_in_all_strings
```

You could use an array of 0s and 1s, indexed by char, to implement a set of chars in C. Or you could use glib (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2502721/2186890). Or maybe consider using a more modern programming language?